# Create an html from the component using innerHTML

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

i am trying to create an html view from a string inside component.

> index.html

```
<div id="div1" [innerHTML]="foo"></div>
```

> index.ts

```
this.foo = `<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Branch</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branches">
            {{branch.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>`;
```

instead of creating the mat-select, it is creating something like this

Branch {{branch.name}}

Comment: i am creating it here because, i am creating based on a response from an API

Comment: How is your API call, component and service file code looks like? You don't need to create template string in ts file. Based on the `branches` array length you can use *ngIf on `mat-form-field`

Comment: And still if you want to create html in ts file. You should not use `*ngFor` and `interpolation` in the ts file. It should be normal javascript code, maybe simple `for` loop and concatination only

Comment: Firstly if you don't use sanitzer you can't add html with all element tags. You need to use sanitzer second problem is that your ngFor element. In binding I am not sure if it will be work or not. Rather than using this create child component then send from api only data and child component type.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve will cause more risk of  XSS attacks, just move the code inside the div

Comment: why dont you put the code inside <div> tags because those mat-label and all wont be parsed by js it is angular which converts them, innerHTML just renders plain html content and it is rendered by js.